# sql) i want String out

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
pr(  v IN VARCHAR2 )  is
begin
     dbms_output.put(v);
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE prt
(  n IN number )  
is
i number :=0;
begin
  LOOP
    i := i+1;
    exit when i=n ;
    pr(i);      
  END LOOP;
  pl(''); --dbms_output.new_line;
END;
/

set serveroutput on

exec prt(5);CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
pr(  v IN VARCHAR2 )  is
begin
     dbms_output.put(v);
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE prt
(  n IN number )  
is
i number :=0;
begin
  LOOP
    i := i+1;
    exit when i=n ;
    pr(i);      
  END LOOP;
  pl(''); --dbms_output.new_line;
END;
/

set serveroutput on

exec prt(5);
```

The code is designed to output only the entered number, but I would like to output a string instead of a number. So I tried to create it with the code pr(i||abc'); but I got an error.I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to correct it so that I can output the text.

Comment: You need to be extremely careful with exit statements. You have *exit when i=n ;* But what happens when someone enters *exec prt(-1)". Answer: runs for a long time, then get overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

You got an "error"? Which error? I don't:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr (v IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v);
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prt (n IN NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3     i  NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5     LOOP
  6        i := i + 1;
  7        EXIT WHEN i = n;
  8        pr (i);
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC prt(5);
1
2
3
4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Concatenated 'abc':

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prt (n IN NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3     i  NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5     LOOP
  6        i := i + 1;
  7        EXIT WHEN i = n;
  8        pr (i || 'abc');       --> concatenated abc
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC prt(5);
1abc
2abc
3abc
4abc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Error occurred when changing pr(i); to pr(i|abc'); in a Loop statement. What I want is to change the result to abc abc abc instead of 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Still works for me; I added that example, have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, compilation errors appear. This seems to be a problem with sql, not with code.

Comment: Which compilation error? Please, edit your initial message and copy/paste your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.